# Querying from ElasticSearch with props (React)

Tags: reactjs, elasticsearch

I am attempting to pass in variables as the arguments for an Elasticsearch query, but the response is coming up empty. Just trying to find out if there's any reason why a var passed into the query would not work but the hard coded string value would.

If I hardcode the exact same values (verified that the arguments passed in are the same from logging to console), the response isn't empty. For example, hardcoded value "ABCD" works but not the value "ABCD" inside the variable parsedMessage that I pass into the query.

I am reluctant to post code because this is a project for work and our repositories are private. But I will post an example that covers exactly what is going on:

```
    GET /my_index/my_type/_search
    {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": { "match": { "title": "quick" }},
       }
      }
    }
```

In this case, "quick" would work. But not logName which is a var string that contains "quick". Neither does if logName contains quick.

Thanks!

Comment: Also: I tried adding quotes and not adding quotes to match the hardcoded value but it seems to not make a difference

Comment: ..but without showing any of the sanitized code, now it's anyone's guess..

Comment: Just updated my question, I was looking for a good generic example online after I posted this

Comment: if you do `".*quick.*"` it will partially match your title.

Comment: @Nicolae Maties : Just tested this out, logName = ".*quick.*" and logName=.*quick.* does not work. But thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this was not an issue with the string LOL :P 
If your string contains quick , it will work (no quotes) 
EX: logName = "quick";
No need to add extra quotes.

My issue had something to do with my database being cleared by a coworker over the weekend.....